# Saving a dinamic SQL query to CSV?

Tags: java, sql, csv

I want to print the results of a query on a CSV file. The problem is the user can write the query from the application so the query change every time (even if only SELECT operations are available).

Any idea how can i extract the data from the `ResultSet` and print them on a CSV?

Comment: I tried save results on a Vector<Vector<Object>> but it's not a good solution since each row print the Object and not the information.

Comment: Try to use ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 1):

You can have this done with [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) quite easily. You just need to get a `ResultSet` from the user's input query and do this:

```
CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines();
routines.write(resultset, new File(path + "SqlClient_" + date + ".csv"), "UTF-8");
```

The write() method takes care of everything. The `resultset` and output file are closed by the routine automatically.

If you want to format the output of specific columns or types (such as dates), you can configure an `ObjectRowWriterProcessor`, for example:

```
ObjectRowWriterProcessor processor = new ObjectRowWriterProcessor();

//assigns a "global" date format conversion for any Timestamp that gets written.
processor.convertType(java.sql.Timestamp.class, Conversions.toDate("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));

//you can also define field-specific conversions, which will override the default setting for timestamps defined above.    
processor.convertFields(Conversions.toDate("dd/MM/yy")).set("created_date", "updated_date");
processor.convertFields(Conversions.trim(), Conversions.toLowerCase()).set("name", "city", "etc");

CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings();
writerSettings.setRowWriterProcessor(processor);

CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines(writerSettings);
routines.write(rs, outputWriter);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok i tried with a different approach:

```
PrintWriter csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new File(path + "SqlClient_" + date + ".csv")) ;
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData() ; 
int numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount() ; 
String dataHeaders = "\"" + meta.getColumnName(1) + "\"" ; 
for (int i = 2 ; i < numberOfColumns + 1 ; i ++ ) { 
            dataHeaders += ",\"" + meta.getColumnName(i) + "\"" ;
}
csvWriter.println(dataHeaders) ;
while (rs.next()) {
        String row = "\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\""  ; 
        for (int i = 2 ; i < numberOfColumns + 1 ; i ++ ) {
             row += ",\"" + rs.getString(i) + "\"" ;
        }
csvWriter.println(row) ;
}
csvWriter.close();
```

Now the rows are printed good but not the columns since the entire row is put on a single column and so the row is not splitted.